# Liveconnect Applet problems

Tags: java, javascript, applet

Cannot call applet methods from javascript. A error appears on the log

-> liveconnect: Security Exception: JavaScript from http:url:port/application attempted to access a resource it has no rights to.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Application-Name: application
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.0.4
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: *
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: *
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_72
Permissions: all-permissions
Codebase: *
```

The java security setting is set to meddium

JRE Version 1.8.0_25-b17

Applet Signed by a trusted source, and the applet jar is downloaded from the same domain as the calling page.

If I try to call the applet method from firebug javascript console another error shows up: Error: Liveconnect call for Applet ID 4 is not allowed in this JVM instance

The applet TAG:

```
  <applet id="applet" code="applet.core.AppletBootstrap" codebase="/applet" archive="applet.jar" width="650" height="500" mayscript="mayscript">
<param name="cache_archive" value="applet.jar"/>
<param name="cache_version" value="2.4.17.2,2.4.17.2,2.4.17.2,2.4.17.2,2.4.17.2"/>
<param name="conversationId" value="e00ed781a56a4378a285d7839a9925bf"/>
<param name="userAgent" value="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.65 Safari/537.36" />
<param name="java_status_events" value="true"/>
<param name="separate_jvm" value="true"/>
<param name="classloader_cache" value="false"/>
<param name="java_arguments" value="-Xmx128m -Djnlp.packEnabled=true "/>
</applet>
```

EDIT:
@Seba JDK-8058697 is a OpenJDK bug related to this issue, unfortunately it is not accessible to me - You can see a duplicate of it: [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8065741)

EDIT 2:
Java 8 update 40 is working again

Comment: Please add the following infos : JRE version ? Applet signed by a trusted source ? JAR in the same domain as the calling page ?

Comment: Ok, I'll update the question

Comment: one-last thing, the HTML tag used to load the Applet.

Comment: Be sure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show.  If there is no output at the default level, raise the level and try it again.

Comment: Hi Andrew, the console appears and it shows the following ~"liveconnect: Security Exception: JavaScript from http:url:port/application attempted to access a resource it has no rights to."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Today I ran into this problem on Ubuntu 14.10, Firefox 35.0.1 & Oracle Java JRE 1.8.0_31.
It is related in some way to JRE utility class in deploy.jar which doesn't work properly on Linux (NativeMixedCodeDialog). On Windows, when you try to access Liveconnect (which implies MIXED security mode) a dialog is shown by this class to kindly ask you for a confirmation. This, for some unknown reasons, doesn't happen on Linux.

You can easily try to check this, by running this command:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -cp /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/deploy.jar com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.ui.NativeMixedCodeDialog "Some Aplet" "Web Site:" "https://localhost" "Publisher:" "Some publisher" "Do not show this again for this app and web site."
```

My solution was to use **Deployment Rule Set** to force Java to trust my app. 
*This might be a no-go for production use, but it let me develop further until this `NativeMixedCodeDialog` gets fixed.*

So straight to the point:

1. Create a file named ruleset.xml
2. Fill it with content according to this [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/deployment_rules.html), for ex.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <ruleset version="1.0+">
     <rule>
       <id location="https://localhost/" />
       <action permission="run" version="SECURE" />
     </rule>
   </ruleset>
   ```
3. Put this into jar

   `jar cvf DeploymentRuleSet.jar ruleset.xml`
4. Sign this jar with certificate valid in `cacerts`, it might be self-signed certificate, but it needs to be found in java cacert file, not just trusted in control panel

   `jarsigner -verbose -keystore ~/selfsigned.p12 -storetype pkcs12 DeploymentRuleSet.jar selfsigned`
5. Copy signed jar to `/etc/.java/deployment/`
6. Possibly restart your browser everything should be working fine

Comment: JDK-8058697 is a OpenJDK bug related to this issue, unfortunately it is not accessible to me - You can see a duplicate of it: [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8065741)

Comment: Thanks - lifesafer! I added some extra commands to this in my own answer (how to generate the selfsigned cert etc)

Comment: It worked, im gonna mark your answer as the right one, and upvote the @stolvik answer.

Answer (score 3):

The answer from @Seba was fantastic, but I can add some commands that you might need:

Create self signed certificate:

```
~/CERTIFICATE $ keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned -keystore keystore.jks -validity 360 -keysize 2048
```

Export the key from the keystore:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias selfsigned -keystore keystore.jks -rfc -file selfsigned.cer
```

Export/Convert the jks keystore into PKCS12 keystore (possibly redundant if you can sign with the ".jks" keystore instead of ".p12" in later step, I did not try):

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.jks -destkeystore keystore.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12
```

Find the cacerts keystore for your java:

```
locate cacerts
...
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

Import key into cacerts:

```
sudo keytool -import -alias selfsigned -file selfsigned.cer -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

And now you create the ruleset.xml file (omit location for "everything", which obviously defeats the security):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ruleset version="1.0+">
  <rule>
   <id />
   <action permission="run" />
  </rule>
</ruleset>
```

Jar it up:

```
jar cvf DeploymentRuleSet.jar ruleset.xml
```

Sign it:

```
jarsigner -verbose -keystore ~/CERTIFICATE/keystore.p12 -storetype pkcs12 DeploymentRuleSet.jar selfsigned
```

**And finally, even though there is a .java/deployment directory in your user's directory, you DO need to copy it to the (possibly non-existent) directory /etc/.java/deployment**

At least for Firefix, you do not need to restart the browser, as long as you kill the java-process that the browser has started. If it is the only java-process around, then running the following command should do it:

```
 killall java
```

Answer (score 0):

I get this error with on Ubuntu 14.04LTE using Firefox 31 and jre1.8.0_25.

On Windows it works fine with various combinations of Windows XP through Windows 8.1 and Firefox, Chrome, IE and different JREs.

I found this link recently which seems to apply directly to my problem:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8064677

Everything worked fine before I added the code signing certificate's CA to the Ubuntu cacerts file. Up till then I had the site in the Java Control Panel Exception Site List.

Once I added the CA cert to cacerts I started getting different Liveconnect problems. I eventually got rid of all of them except for the one you're getting.

I've tried http and https but nothing helps.

If I learn anything more I'll let you know.